# mysql_config not found with mysql-community on CentOS 7

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, centos7

I need to install `mysqlclient` module for python3.6 on my CentOS server via `pip`.
The instalation breaks with following error: `OSError: mysql_config not found`.
I've found a solution, to install `mysql-devel` package, but unfortunately it breaks with following error:

```
Error: mariadb101u-config conflicts with mysql-community-server-8.0.4-0.1.rc.el7.x86_64
Error: mariadb101u-libs conflicts with mysql-community-libs-8.0.4-0.1.rc.el7.x86_64
Error: mariadb101u-libs conflicts with mysql-community-libs-compat-8.0.4-0.1.rc.el7.x86_64
Error: mariadb101u-common conflicts with mysql-community-common-8.0.4-0.1.rc.el7.x86_64
```

I cannot remove the mysql-community packages, because the server is running MySQL database based on that.
Is there any way to fix it without removing conflicting packets?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Ok, found an answer:

```
yum install mariadb-devel gcc python36u-devel
```

Comment: Your solution worked for me. However, while installing mariadb-devel through yum, I kept on getting a connection time out. So I downloaded the mariadb-devel manually and installed it manually through yum.

Comment: yum install mariadb-devel gcc python38-devel

Answer (score 3):

Solution by @Djent worked for me.

But I kept on receiving time out error while installing through yum. If you are having the same problem. You can manually download the package and install it!
On CentOS

```
wget https://archive.mariadb.org/mariadb-10.1.39/yum/centos7-amd64/rpms/MariaDB-10.1.38-centos73-x86_64-devel.rpm
rpm -i MariaDB-10.1.38-centos73-x86_64-devel.rpm
```

For other linux OS, you can find mariadb-devel at https://pkgs.org/download/mariadb-devel

Answer (score 0):

First run the command (take note of *python* version):

```
sudo yum install python36-devel
```

Then install *mysqlclient* using *pip*.