# mariadb-devel does not work on Cent OS 7 while using yum

Tags: python, mysql

I tried installing mariadb in my CentOS using the following command.

```
yum install mariadb-devel
```

But I get the following error:

```
MariaDB-10.1.38-centos73-x86_6 FAILED                                          
http://yum.mariadb.org/10.1/centos7-amd64/rpms/MariaDB-10.1.38-centos73-x86_64-devel.rpm: [Errno 12] Timeout on http://yum.mariadb.org/10.1/centos7-amd64/rpms/MariaDB-10.1.38-centos73-x86_64-devel.rpm: (28, 'Operation too slow. Less than 1000 bytes/sec transferred the last 30 seconds')
Trying other mirror.
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [mysql\_config not found with mysql-community on CentOS 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49666481/mysql-config-not-found-with-mysql-community-on-centos-7)